# 'Contact detail' or 'contact details'?

Tags: grammatical-number

When I ask anyone his contact details, how do I do it?

> Give me your contact details.

or

> Give me your contact detail.

?

Comment: You could avoid this entirely by asking for their contact *information*, which is more commonly heard.

Comment: This question is too basic for this site. Please support the proposed site targeted specifically at [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should say **contact details**. The reason is that a person could have more than one contact details, e.g, phone number, email address, Facebook account, etc. That's why you can't use *contact detail*, which refers to a single item.

You might be wondering  what if you wanted to ask for a phone number or email address, wouldn't it be possible to use **contact detail**? The answer is no, because it becomes ambiguous and it's better to mention the name of that contact detail, e.g, *can I have your phone number?*

Finally, you can use *contact detail*  not *contact details* as a modifier for other words, e.g, *contact detail pages*.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask someone their contact *details*, you obviously ask them for their contact *details*:

> Give me your contact details.

A *please* wouldn't harm either :)

> Could I please have your contact details?

Comment: Sorry! My question was whether I could say `detail` instead of `details`.

Comment: @TabrezAhmed: Didn't I answer that?

Comment: Sorry if i've misunderstood. But if I say `contact detail` will it be wrong ?

Comment: @TabrezAhmed: If you want a specific contact detail, i.e. phone number, you should ask for the phone number, not "the contact detail" or "a contact detail". I don't really understand what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

Armen's response is correct, but I would add that it is more common to ask for contact information, rather than contact details.

> What is your contact information?

Or simpler still, to ask for the specific contact information you are seeking (what is your email address, or what is your phone number, etc).

Comment: Sorry! My question was whether I could say `detail` instead of `details`.

Comment: In that respect, Armens response is correct. 'Detail' is not acceptable, 'details' is.